# c# error cs0117 'System.Diagnostics.Debug' does not contain a definition for 'Log'

Tags: c#

I don't know why I am getting this error. I am using Repl.it at school since we are using chromebooks, but I don't think the C# would be different. I'm debugging some code just to see what it looks like in the console, but it just simply won't work. I am just getting errors. I'm using System.Diagnostics, System.IO, and System.

I know C# pretty well, so I don't think I'm missing anything. I believe it's just simply a Repl.it issue.

Here is my C# code:

```cs
public char firstchar = 'a';
public char lasrchar = 'z';

public int passwordLength = 6;
public long tries = 0;

public bool done = false;

public string password = "hey";

public void CreatePasswords(string keys) 
{
    if (keys == password) 
    {
        done = true;
    }
    if (keys.Length == passwordLength || done == true) 
    {
        return;
    }
    for (char c = firstchar; c <= lasrchar; c++) 
    {
        tries++;
        CreatePasswords(keys + c);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    Program program = new Program();

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    Console.WriteLine("welcome to my brute force password cracker.");

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

    Console.Write("this program was created by ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.Write("Volt");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    Console.WriteLine(".");

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2800);

    Console.WriteLine("note that passwords found in under a second won't tell you how many passwords per second they got.");

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
    Console.Write("\nplease enter your password > ");

    program.password = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    program.password = program.password.ToLower();

    //Debug.Log(program.password = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()));
    //Debug.Log(program.password = program.password.ToLower());

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    Console.WriteLine("\ncracking your password...");

    Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    program.passwordLength = program.password.Length;
    program.CreatePasswords(string.Empty);
    timer.Stop();

    //Debug.Log(program.passwordLength = program.password.Length);
    //Debug.Log(program.CreatePasswords(string.Empty));

    long elapsedMs = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    double elapsedTime = elapsedMs / 1000;

    if (elapsedTime > 0) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nyour password has been found! here are the statistics:");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("password: {0}", program.password);
        Console.WriteLine("password length: {0}", program.passwordLength);
        Console.WriteLine("tries: {0}", program.tries);

        string plural = "seconds";

        if (elapsedTime == 1) 
        {
            plural = "second";
        }
        Console.WriteLine("time to crack: {0} {1}", elapsedTime, plural);
        Console.WriteLine("passwords per second: {0}", (long)(program.tries / elapsedTime));
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nyour password has been found! here are the statistics:");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("password: {0}", program.password);
        Console.WriteLine("password length: {0}", program.passwordLength);
        Console.WriteLine("tries: {0}", program.tries);
        Console.WriteLine("time to crack: {0} seconds", elapsedTime);
    }
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
    Console.Write("\n\npress any key to close");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Please note, this isn't an actual brute force password cracker. I simply made this for fun.

Comment: Debug doesn't contain a definition for Log because there is no `Debug.Log` method.  It doesn't exist. You probably want `Debug.WriteLine`. `Debug.Log` is a Unity Engine method, not .NET.